# Header inclusion problems

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, tor

I'm having issues compiling Tor after modifying it a bit.

In a file called `control.c`, I added code that refers to a struct called `rend_service_t` (which is located in `rendservice.h`). I included `rendservice.h` to the top of `control.c`, as it wasn't including it previously.

If I try using the Makefile included, I get this error:

```
control.c:2841: error: 'rend_service_t' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I'm guessing that `rendservice.c` isn't getting included or isn't getting compiled first, so I check the directory and there isn't an object file for rendservice. I'm a bit confused by this since it is clearly being included. 
What is causing this to happen?

I also tried editing the `Makefile.am/.in` so that `rendservice.c/h` comes before `control.c/h`, but it doesn't make any difference.

In `control.c`:

```
...
#include "rendservice.h"
...
static int
handle_control_addservice(control_connection_t *conn, uint32_t len,
                             const char *body)
{
  smartlist_t *args;
  rend_service_t *service;
...
```

In `rendservice.c`:

```
...
/** Represents a single hidden service running at this OP. */
typedef struct rend_service_t {
  /* Fields specified in config file */
  char *directory; /**< where in the filesystem it stores it */
  smartlist_t *ports; /**< List of rend_service_port_config_t */
  rend_auth_type_t auth_type; /**< Client authorization type or 0 if no client
                               * authorization is performed. */
  smartlist_t *clients; /**< List of rend_authorized_client_t's of
                         * clients that may access our service. Can be NULL
                         * if no client authorization is performed. */
  /* Other fields */
  crypto_pk_env_t *private_key; /**< Permanent hidden-service key. */
  char service_id[REND_SERVICE_ID_LEN_BASE32+1]; /**< Onion address without
                                                  * '.onion' */
  char pk_digest[DIGEST_LEN]; /**< Hash of permanent hidden-service key. */
  smartlist_t *intro_nodes; /**< List of rend_intro_point_t's we have,
                             * or are trying to establish. */
  time_t intro_period_started; /**< Start of the current period to build
                                * introduction points. */
  int n_intro_circuits_launched; /**< Count of intro circuits we have
                                  * established in this period. */
  rend_service_descriptor_t *desc; /**< Current hidden service descriptor. */
  time_t desc_is_dirty; /**< Time at which changes to the hidden service
                         * descriptor content occurred, or 0 if it's
                         * up-to-date. */
  time_t next_upload_time; /**< Scheduled next hidden service descriptor
                            * upload time. */
  /** Map from digests of Diffie-Hellman values INTRODUCE2 to time_t of when
   * they were received; used to prevent replays. */
  digestmap_t *accepted_intros;
  /** Time at which we last removed expired values from accepted_intros. */
  time_t last_cleaned_accepted_intros;
} rend_service_t;
...
```

Comment: Can you show the code how `rend_service_t` is declared? And the code that uses `rend_service_t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rend_service_t` is a structure that's private to `rendservice.c` - it doesn't appear to be intended for use outside that .c file, and it's not declared in `rendservice.h`. (See the version of `rendservice.c` that I;m looking at here: https://doxygen.torproject.org/rendservice_8c_source.html).

So this isn't a header inclusion problem - the structure isn't delcared in the header at all.

You should ask a question about what you what you intended to use `struct rend_service_t` for.

Comment: Is it possible just to 'publicize' the struct? Or should I just write the function in `rendservice.c` and `rendservice.h` and call it from `control.c`?

Comment: @Kevin: I'm not at all familiar with the code base. You could probably move the structure into some header that's used by both source files, but I suspect that there would be more refactoring involved. It looks like many of the functions that deal with the structure are marked `static` in `rendservice.c`, so I'd guess that you'd at least need to make some or all of those externally accessible. Also, the `rend_service_t` structure may aggregate several other structures that need similar treatment...

Answer (score 0):

Your file control.c is being compiled and is generating a compile error. Doesn't matter whether rendservice.c is compiled before or after. All the compiler looks at is control.c and any headers it pulls in.

Probably the definition of rend_service_t is inside an ifdef section and so the compiler is skipping it. Likely you need to #define REND_SERVICE or something similar... Have a look in rendservice.h and see if the read_service_t definition is inside an ifdef block.

Comment: I checked for any ifndefs/ifdefs, and the only one that exists is to prevent including the header twice, `#ifndef _TOR_RENDSERVICE_H... #define _TOR_RENDSERVICE_H` etc